# How to manage Certificate Authority(CA) with IBM Security Access Manager for Web 8.0.1

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, isam, webseal

Hi I am referring the following link to 
    1. create a Certificate Authority (CA),
    2. Issuing a server certificate with a CA, and
    3. Distributing the CA root certificate to clients in IBM Security Access Manager.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/security/tutorials/se-gskit/

But, now i have IBM Security Access Manager for Web 8.0.1 And using the WebUI I need to manage the same.

Can anyone have the appropriate document, links or solution, using which i can do the same as one can do using GSKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still use GSKit to manage your certificates. Create your keystores on another machine (e.g. your desktop) and the import them into the appliance.

http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_8.0.1/com.ibm.isamw.doc_8.0.1/admin/task/tsk_lmi_key_db_imp.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have used GSKit to manage my certificates. And imported key database and stash file into ISAM 8 using WebUI, after that configured my junction to use that database (.kdb).

I used only one .kdb file which made me easy to import it in ISAM 8. There is no compulsion to have separate databases for CA and your server.

To create CA use: [http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/security/tutorials/se-gskit/](https://developer.ibm.com/solutions/security/)

And to import created CA's DB and stash file follow steps from: [http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_8.0.1/com.ibm.isamw.doc_8.0.1/admin/task/tsk_lmi_key_db_imp.html?lang=en](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/sva/8.0.1?topic=certificates-importing-certificate-database)